System.UserManagement class to execute passwordless login on Experience Site
We're trying to implement passwordless login (with an emailed one time code) into our customer facing experience site. The requirement is to have a custom Verification page, so for this reason I've ruled out using the Site.passwordlessLogin method.
I've been trying to use the paired methods in UserManagement, so UserManagement.initPasswordlessLogin and UserManagement.verifyVerificationMethod.
I'm running the code from a VF page embedded in an experience site, which is executed by the Guest User. When trying to call UserManagement.initPasswordlessLogin I'm receiving a System.NoAccessException: Script-thrown exception error
Code within the Apex controller calling the method is below (this is rough code as it's all a PoC at the moment):
public void sendVerificationCode(){
    User communityUser = CommunityHelper.getCommunityUserByUsername(emailAddress, new Set<String>{'id'});
    try {
        identifier = System.UserManagement.initPasswordlessLogin(communityUser.id, Auth.VerificationMethod.EMAIL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        system.debug('exception');
        system.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
}


The try/catch you have is mostly just getting in the way (a pokemon catch (catching the top-level exception class, gotta catch 'em all) is usually a red flag. Just debugging and swallowing the exception is another red flag). If you remove it, you should end up getting a better/more complete error message.

Just to avoid confusion have you checked configs that access is setup correctly for guest user
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_identity_passwordless_custom_verification.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_monitor_verification_methods.htm&type=5

Take a look at Headless Passwordless
